how to build hyperlinked tex.tex
I download tex.web and build with commands:
weave tex.web
pdftex tex.tex

then i get tex.pdf. but my build tex.pdf don't have table of contents, bookmarks and cross-references.
but when I open tex.pdf in texlive\texmf-dist\doc\generic\knuth-pdf\tex\tex.pdf, it has all table of contents, bookmarks and cross-references, for example:

so, can anyone guide me, how to build tex.pdf like in texlive? Because I want to translate it to Chinese, and I want to keep table of contents, bookmarks and cross-references also. Thanks!

How many times did you run pdftex? Those elements typically require at least two compilation cycles.

I also try run multi-times pdftex. But no matter how many times I run pdftex, I still can't get cross-references tex.pdf.

weave -p is intended to produce a .tex file more suited to PDF output. (Or, rather, two such files.) Processing the resulting tex.tex with pdftex causes compilation errors, but does include hyperlinks. Using pdftex -ini compiles it without error, but I don't get hyperlinks in that case. (At least, I couldn't find any quickly so I assume there aren't any.) Missing something ... If you could ping random people, I'd ask where wipet is when you need your resident TeXnophile, but it doesn't, so I shan't.

Thank you! I find some hint from latex-tds package maintained by Heiko Oberdiek. The package description said "This bundle provides a set of zip file modules containing TDS-compliant trees for items of the LATEX distribution (both the base system and required packages), together with ‘user-friendly’ documentation (PDF files with navigation support using bookmarks and links).". I think maybe Heiko Oberdiek know this question's answer.

Also the package knuth-pdf maintained by Andreas Scherer has the tex.pdf with cross-references. But Andreas Scherer don't introduce how to build them.

This is definitely nothing to do with latex ....
